# How do I load results using php and jquery as I scroll?

Tags: php, jquery

How do I load results using php and jquery as I scroll? E.g. like twitter, facebook and Especially http://cssline.com/

Answer (score 2):

It is called infinite scrolling here is [how to do it with images](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/), It should get you going I guess.

See the demo [here](http://alexandrupitea.ro/nettuts/scroll/), it's quite similar.

It is done with PHP and AJAX (in this case)

Comment: @GingerBill No problem, it might need some modification but I'm sure it will get you going! Good luck, tell me if you need anything...

Comment: Ok thanks, It seems like what I need but I'll have to tweak it a lot to get it to work.

Comment: @GingerBill Ok good luck!! please tell us if you need any help with the tweaking ;)

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is "infinite scroll". Google it and you'll find plenty of results.